# Parsing a single row of JSON in android

Tags: android, json, listview

I am trying to create an app which parses a JSON and populates the listview. What I want is whenever an item is clicked the relevant data is parsed from the JSON. For example :

Activity 1:

contains a list of famous personalities

1 Mahatma Gandhi

2 Abraham lincoln

3 Nelson Mandela

4 Queen Elizabeth

Activity 2

Displays the Biography of the clicked item of listview. JSON for second activity contains a list of Biographies of the personalities

Now what I want to do is whenever an item of the listview is clicked the JSON of that particular item is parsed.Like if Mahatma Gandhi is clicked , then only the biography if Mahatma Gandhi i.e only the first row of the JSON array is fetched in the second activity

**EDIT**

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    public ArrayList<Person> users;
    public RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String url = "http://www.humanfox.com/capsule/dash.php";
    NetworkImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        imageView=(NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, lv,false);

        lv.addHeaderView(header);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try{
                    JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("result");
                    users = Person.fromJson(ja);
                    lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, users));
                }
                catch(JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");

                    }
                }
        );
        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jor);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                                    long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, caps1.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }


}
```

When the item is clicked on the listview how do I set an onclicklistener so that it parses the the row no. of Json similar to the id of the listview clicked .E.g
if the item no. 3 is clicked on the listview . row no. 3 of the json is parsed in the 2nd activity

Comment: what i want is you code them yourself and if you run into a problem, ask it here

Comment: I have already...........just wanted a suggestion

Comment: show me the code and what error you are getting

Comment: i just updated....and I am not getting an error I want to know how the parsing of relevant row according to clicking of item of listview can be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the json array and keep the biographies in a java bean (getters and setters) so after doing this you will have an ArrayList of biographies (ex: new Biography(name, age, lifesummary)). You can get the list view index of the selected biography and pass the bean class (Parceable) to the second activity (using intent putextra) and display the desired result there.

Comment: you have to create a model class as he told! which have all getters and setters of ur Json objects and in ur second activity get id of the item and show that object

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't keep the data in form of JSON or something like that. Application need Models such as: Person, FamousPerson, Country ... which hold data inside. Consider to use GSON library to do that in efficient way.

For example, with json data:

{ "t_id": "123SBD2SF"; "t_name": "Abraham lincoln"; }

You'll have corresponding model:

```
public class FamousPerson {
    @SerializedName("t_id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("t_name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("your json object key")
    private ...

    // get, set function
}
```

With GSON just call mGson.fromJson(jsonString, FamousPerson.class). And data is handled automatically